# C# mysqldrivercs dataset UpdateCommand

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using mysqldrivercs to connect to my mysql database.

Now I have some problems. I read my data into a dataset and i make some changes. I would like to update the change to my database.

But mysqldrivercs doesn't supply a way like "sqlcommandbuilder", so i don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't there a `MySqlCommandBuilder`? I suppose you're using mysql net connector.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommandbuilder.html

Comment: I'm using mysqldrivercs ,and this doesn't supply MySqlCommandBuilder for sure.

Comment: But thank you for suggesting me to use mysql net connector, i may try this later.